# adding an external library in the Android CDT

Tags: android, eclipse-cdt

I'm using the android ADT bundle for Linux with the CDT 8.0.2.+NDK support.
I need to add an external library. I checked on the Eclipse forum for example here:

[linking-external-lib](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_do_I_add_an_external_library_to_my_C.2B.2B_project.3F)

The problem is that it looks like the Android CDT does not have the same settings. Neither of the three solutions can be applied.

Did anyone find the way to add an external .so library in eclipse with CDT?

Before I added the Native spport I used to have the .so file in the libs folder. Now the libs folder is cleared everytime I build the project. So I need to put it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by adding the following lines to the Android.mk

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE:=libname

LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= path-to-lib/libname.so

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)